# os.path.splitext(file.txt.gz) into (file,.txt.gz)

Tags: python, string, os.path

Currently, I have files that end in /path_to_file/file.txt.gz.

I would like to split the extract the filename (before the .txt.gz).

```
x = os.path.basename("/path_to_file/file.txt.gz")
```

gives me

```
file.txt.gz
```

while

```
os.path.splitext("file.txt.gz")
```

gives me

```
('file.txt','.gz')
```

Is there a function that would separate 'file' from '.txt.gz'?

I suppose I could just use re.sub(), but was wondering if there exists an os.path function.

Thanks.

Comment: just do a normal 'file.txt.gz'.split('.') gives you ['file', 'txt', 'gz'], wouldn't this be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprised that no one has mentioned that the `str.split` [method takes an argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the maximum number of times to split on that character: e.g., `filepath.split('.', 1)`.

Comment: This is much simpler!

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "/path_to_file/file.txt.gz"
basename = os.path.basename(s) # file.txt.gz
filename = basename[:basename.find('.')] # file
extension = basename[basename.find('.'):] # txt.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very easily. Just try:

```
import os

filename = os.path.split(path)[1]
filename_wout_ext = filename.split('.')[0]
```

An example would be:

```
>>> path = "/path_to_file/file.txt.gz"
>>> filename = os.path.split(path)[1]
>>> filename
>>> 'file.txt.gz'
>>> filename_wout_ext = filename.split('.')[0]
>>> filename_wout_ext
>>> 'file'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
".".join(os.path.basename("/path_to_file/file.txt.gz").split('.')[:1])

>>'file'

os.path.splitext(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename("/path_to_file/file.txt.gz"))[0])[0]

>>'file'
```